# in i3wm how can I set the default layout for all works spaces

Tags: linux, defaults

By default when you start i3wm all work spaces start as vertical/horizontal split `splith/splitv` layout.

Is there a way to set the a different default like `stacking` or `tabbed` as the default for all containers on all work spaces. Some thing I can added to my `~/.i3/config`

In stead of manually specifying each work space to use a specific layout using the `mod+"w|e|s"`

https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_the_container_layout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to change the behaviour of *all* new workspaces, just add

```
workspace_layout stacking
```

(or `tabbed` or `default`) to your `.i3/config` file, see section 4.8 of the documentation.  The `default` is either horizontal, vertical or automatic, and governed by the `default_orientation` option, see section 4.7.

You can have finer-grained control using airblader's [per-workspace-layout.pl](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/blob/gaps-next/contrib/per-workspace-layout.pl) script in the `contrib` directory
and also using the [layout-saving and restoring](http://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) feature.

Comment: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_layout_mode_for_new_containers